# Rails: Cucumber and Application Controller Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I am doing integration testing using Cucumber. In my `ApplicationController`, I have a method called `current_user` that provides the current user object. I use this object to add items to a redis database:

```
$redis.sadd("cart#current_user.id}", [1,5,2])
```

In my Cucumber steps I test this functionality:

```
Then /^the redis database should have "(.+)" item ids/ do |count|
  expect($redis.smembers("cart#{current_user.id}").count).to eq count.to_i
end
```

However, it is my understanding that Cucumber does not have access to controller methods, even if they are under `ApplicationController`, and therefore I cannot user the `current_user` method the way I would in my controllers.

What I am doing now is since I am testing features, there is only one user in the database so the current_user.id will always be 1, but if I start adding more users this may not work nicely.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm figuring that at some point in your test suite, you register or log in with a user. At that point you need to get the user id somehow, and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not really using Cucumber as intended here. What you are doing is testing how your application currently works, but really Cukes is best used to specify what your application does and why its important.

Applying more appropriate usage to your current problem leads to the following questions

What is the reason for storing the ids in Redis?
What benefit does the customer get by having these id's stored?

Taking a wild guess you might be saving a basket so that if the user logs out, their basket would still be populated when they come back. Then your scenario would be something like

```
Scenario: Remember products in basket
  Given I am registered
  And I am logged in
  When I put some products in my basket
  And I log out
  And I log in again
  Then my basket should still have some products in it
```

Notice how the scenario is all about WHAT you are doing and WHY its important but reveals nothing about HOW this is going to be done. This is a really good way to critique scenarios. Scenarios that contain HOW stuff are going to be harder to write and much harder to maintain. Anyhow enough of that :)

Now you can use standard cucumber stuff like assigned the user to a variable in one step e.g. `@i = create_registered_user` and then using that user in the other steps e.g. `login as: @i`

Note that we don't look at the database, only at what the user sees, and we don't reveal anything about HOW this functionality works in the scenario.

If you want to write tests (rather than scenarios) that do reveal how functionality works and do look at databases for results then I'd suggest that rspec would be better suited for this.

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. I am still wrapping my head around types of tests, what they are used for, what tools to use for each test, etc. I'm getting there :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

do you have a step to login? if so, you can change it a little so you can control which user logs in:

```
Given "john_doe" logs in to the app
```

Then you can search by username and do the login in your step. You can do the same on this step:

```
Then /^the redis database should have "(.+)" item ids/ do |count|
```

something like

```
Then /^the redis database should have "(.+)" item ids for user "(.*)"/ do |count, user_name|
  user = User.find_by(username: user_name)
  expect($redis.smembers("cart#{user.id}").count).to eq count.to_i
end
```

Comment: I have separate tests that do exactly as you have it. However, if a user doesn't exist then at some point (e.g. when a user checks out) the app automatically logs a user in as a Guest User. When this happens, the guest user's id can be any random id and the user would have no name, password, email etc, but would have an id. In my app, I can access the id of the guest user by using the current_user method. After some digging, I figured out that I wasn't testing the most optimal way and I shouldn't need to access the current_user method. Thanks for the response!